# react-native-maps - Very low resolution with OpenStreetMap

Tags: react-native, openstreetmap, resolution, react-native-maps, blurry

I'm using react-native-maps in React Native and I wanted to use OpenStreetMap (because Google Map is incredibly expensive for a commercial project). MapView gives very low resolution tiles, the tiles and labels are very blurry (see pictures below).

This code is working perfectly with Google Maps:

```
import MapView, {
  MAP_TYPES,
  PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
  PROVIDER_GOOGLE,
} from "react-native-maps";
...
<MapView
  ref={(map) => (currentMap = map)}
  initialRegion={location}
  showsUserLocation
  style={{
    height: Globals.Layout.window.height,
    width: Globals.Layout.window.width,
  }}
></MapView>
```

[Google map result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beuaS.jpg)

---

Change to this to use OpenStreetMap, and you get correct tiles, but everything is blurred and in low resolution :

```
import MapView, {
  MAP_TYPES,
  PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
  PROVIDER_GOOGLE,
} from "react-native-maps";
...
<MapView
  ref={(map) => (currentMap = map)}
  initialRegion={location}
  showsUserLocation
  provider={PROVIDER_DEFAULT}
  mapType={MAP_TYPES.NONE}
  style={{
    height: Globals.Layout.window.height,
    width: Globals.Layout.window.width,
  }}
>
    <MapView.UrlTile
      urlTemplate={"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}
      shouldReplaceMapContent={true}
    />
</MapView>
```

[OpenStreetMap result (very blurry)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERnia.jpg)

---

Environment info:

- react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0
- react-native: 0.61.4
- react-native-maps: 0.26.1

---

How can I do to make the resolution of the tiles higher (or simulate a zoom-out?)

Comment: You need to use a different tile source with support of [high-resolution tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/High-resolution_tiles), also called retina tiles.

Comment: I don't know if it is of help, but OSM encourages users to run their own tile server - maybe that would fix the res problem?

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I see tiles in a higher zoom that are not loaded yet. Instead, your application uses the the tiles from the lower zoom and scales than until the right tiles are loaded. Your problem is that you are using openstreetmap.org as a tile source which is a bad business idea. Their infrastructure is totally overloaded. openstreetmap.org also update their data minutely and rerender the tiles if data changes occur to support mappers. But this makes it unuseful for external applications that just want to show the map.

Use a different tile provider that is based on OSM data but that is optimized for websites and apps and caches tiles in an intelligent way for fast delivery. This will cost some bucks but far less than G Maps.

Comment: well he is already using react-native-maps

Comment: @showtime: but he is using tiles provided by the OSMF as a source and those carry a low resolution. React-nativemaps is just a client, important is the source serving the tiles and the resolution of those served tiles. To use tiles with a higher resolution that are not blurry, this would help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444988/label-size-in-osm-tiles/445056#445056

Comment: however, I tried implementing it but it doesnt show any OSM maps. It keeps showing google maps.

Comment: @showtime: the threadstarter replaced the standard map by overwriting the map content here: `<MapView.UrlTile
      urlTemplate={"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}
      shouldReplaceMapContent={true}
    />`

Comment: shouldReplaceMapContent flag is only for iOS, I have tried in Android without that flag, and replacing the map via urlTemplate. Someone else in another forum told me that urlTemplate only puts an overlay, meaning you will still be charged for google maps. Is that correct?